# Django-CMS test - register app

Tags: django, django-cms, django-testing

I have a function to build some skeleton of CMS in my tests:

```
def create_base_cms_structure():
    from cms.api import create_page
    from cms.utils.conf import get_cms_setting
    superuser = User.objects.create_superuser('cmsadmin', 'admin@admin.com', 'cmsadmin')
    create_page('account-page', get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')[0][0], 'pl',
                created_by=superuser, published=True, apphook="AccountApp")
    create_page('job-page', get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')[0][0], 'pl',
                created_by=superuser, published=True, apphook="JobApp")
    create_page('article-page', get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')[0][0], 'pl',
                created_by=superuser, published=True, apphook="ArticleApp")
```

Is it ok? When I try to run my tests using Client() I get error that 1 of my reverse doesn't exists (the one from account app). That URL is being rendered in main template.

Do I miss something?

**Django 1.4.5**

**Django-CMS 2.4b**

Comment: Just curios what version of both Django and Django-cms are you using?

Comment: @SidharthShah just edited my post:)

Answer (score 0):

From the Django-cms documentation:

> Your apps need testing, but in your live site they aren’t in urls.py as they are attached to a CMS page. So if you want to be able to use reverse() in your tests, or test templates that use the url template tag, you need to hook up your app to a special test version of urls.py and tell your tests to use that.

and then

```
@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='myapp.tests.urls')
```

before your method.

http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/testing.html

Have you tried this?